# Radio Button check by code uwp

Tags: c#, button, uwp

I have a uwp app and I've add two Radio Buttons for change theme from black to white

but I couldn't change the check using `isChecked`

everytime my app crash and close

Here's my Code

```
           if (localSettings.Values["Theme"] != null)
        {
            string R = localSettings.Values["Theme"].ToString();
            if (R == "light")
            {
                RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
                white.IsChecked = true;
                black.IsChecked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
                black.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
            black.IsChecked = true;
            white.IsChecked = false;
        }
```

Picture

[image]

Comment: At which line does it throw exception?

Comment: @KostyaK I've deleted them all and I've let just one of them 

the code `White.IsChecked = true` or the another one and the app close in everytime  ...

Comment: Can you run it from Visual Studio in Debug mode and see what exception happens there?

Comment: @KostyaK Post refreshed

Comment: @KostyaK thanks for your help

Comment: no problem.            ___

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form (XAML) which contains the radio button is not initialized.

Ensure you do set values to your controls once `InitializeComponent()` function is called for your form.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use something that is null. This means you either set it to null, or you never set it to anything at all. In your case, it is the check box called **Black**. You can solve the app crashing and closing issue by handling the null value. In addition, you can display the error as a message by inserting try and catch block in order to solve the issue of crashing and closing apps. Show more code for black and white checkbox in order to help you with more specifically.